# Symfony assetic sass filter via node-sass?

Tags: ruby, node.js, symfony, sass

I'm having some difficulties getting an assetic sass filter to work with `node-sass` instead of the ruby alternative. I have the following configuration in my `config.yml` file:

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"

    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]

    write-to:       "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/assets"
    read_from:      "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/assets"

    node:        "%%PROGRAMFILES%%\nodejs\\node.exe"
    node_paths: ["%%USERPROFILE%%\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules"]
    sass:        "%%USERPROFILE%%\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node-sass"
    ruby: null

    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        scss:
            output-style: compressed
            apply_to: "\.(scss|sass|css)%"
```

Although this triggers the right `node-sass` command, I'm not sure the configuration is correct. If I remove `ruby: null` it tries to run `C:\Program Files...\path\to\ruby.exe %%USERPROFILE%%\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node-sass` which is totally wrong. But having `ruby: null` doesn't solve the problem as well, because it sets the wrong arguments (i.e `--load-path` instead of `--include-path`) and that messes things as well.

Does anybody know how to set the `sass` filter with `node` instead of `ruby`?

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to share my solution to this issue for anybody out there who might be experiencing it as well.

It appears that the `BaseSassFilter` is suited to work only with the ruby version. So I decided to create my own filter. Here is my class:

```
<?php

namespace App\YourBundle\Assetic\Filter;

use Assetic\Asset\AssetInterface;
use Assetic\Exception\FilterException;
use Assetic\Filter\Sass\BaseSassFilter;
use Assetic\Filter\Sass\SassFilter;

/**
 * This class is based on Assetic\Filter\Sass\SassFilter and is slightly modified to work with node-sass instead of Ruby.
 */

class NodeSassFilter extends BaseSassFilter
{

    const STYLE_NESTED     = 'nested';
    const STYLE_EXPANDED   = 'expanded';
    const STYLE_COMPACT    = 'compact';
    const STYLE_COMPRESSED = 'compressed';

    private $sassPath;
    private $scss;
    private $style;
    private $quiet;
    private $cacheLocation;

    public function __construct($sassPath = '/usr/bin/node-sass')
    {
        $this->sassPath = $sassPath;
        $this->cacheLocation = realpath(sys_get_temp_dir());
    }

    public function setScss($scss)
    {
        $this->scss = $scss;
    }

    public function setStyle($style)
    {
        $this->style = $style;
    }

    public function setQuiet($quiet)
    {
        $this->quiet = $quiet;
    }

    public function filterLoad(AssetInterface $asset)
    {
        $sassProcessArgs = array($this->sassPath);

        $pb = $this->createProcessBuilder($sassProcessArgs);

        if ($dir = $asset->getSourceDirectory()) {
            $pb->add('--include-path')->add($dir);
        }

        if ($this->style) {
            $pb->add('--output-style')->add($this->style);
        }

        if ($this->quiet) {
            $pb->add('--quiet');
        }

        // input
        $pb->add($input = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'assetic_sass'));
        file_put_contents($input, $asset->getContent());

        $proc = $pb->getProcess();
        $code = $proc->run();
        unlink($input);

        if (0 !== $code) {
            throw FilterException::fromProcess($proc)->setInput($asset->getContent());
        }

        $asset->setContent($proc->getOutput());
    }

    public function filterDump(AssetInterface $asset)
    {
    }
}
```

Then, in your `config.yml` you add the following:

```
assetic:
    filters:
        nodesass:
            bin: "%sass.bin%"
            resource: '%kernel.root_dir%/config/filters/nodesass.xml'
            style: compressed
            apply_to: "\.scss%"
```

In `app/config/filters/nodesass.xml` you add the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <parameters>
        <parameter key="assetic.filter.nodesass.class">App\YourBundle\Assetic\Filter\NodeSassFilter</parameter>
        <parameter key="assetic.filter.nodesass.bin">%assetic.sass.bin%</parameter>
        <parameter key="assetic.filter.nodesass.timeout">240</parameter>
        <parameter key="assetic.filter.nodesass.style">null</parameter>
        <parameter key="assetic.filter.nodesass.load_paths" type="collection" />
    </parameters>

    <services>
        <service id="assetic.filter.nodesass" class="%assetic.filter.nodesass.class%">
            <tag name="assetic.filter" alias="nodesass" />
            <argument>%assetic.filter.nodesass.bin%</argument>
            <call method="setTimeout"><argument>%assetic.filter.nodesass.timeout%</argument></call>
            <call method="setStyle"><argument>%assetic.filter.nodesass.style%</argument></call>
            <call method="setLoadPaths"><argument>%assetic.filter.nodesass.load_paths%</argument></call>
        </service>
    </services>

</container>
```

This should get things working for now.

Comment: Good work. This should go in the assetic repository, I also manage assets mainly via node without ruby.

Comment: I'll check if they haven't already fixed this in the latest versions and make a PR when I have some time in that case.  :)

Comment: OK anyway thanks - I spent a couple of hours messing with load-path (ruby sass) vs load-imports (node-sass)... to finally realize that the sass filters is meant to be used with ruby :)

Comment: I made a node-sass filter github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/pull/767 that works quite like yours. It seems working fine.

Comment: Let's hope @gremo 's PR is merged soon!